# Сохранение состояния элемента с помощью SQlite

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

В процессе моего обучения разработки для Android поднялась тема сохранения параметров приложения. В частности, нужно по нажатию на пункт списка `ListView` менять бекграунд этого списка и сохранять изменение. Решил вопрос с помощью `SharedPreferences`.
Но! Теперь хочу попробовать новый способ, сохранение значения в БД. Уже подсказали, что нужно определить поле в базе:

```
public static final boolean COMPLETE = false;
```

И как-то это использовать, а как? Хотя бы примерно?

Comment: Тебя обманули в sqlite3 нету типа boolean, надо хранить int 0/1

Comment: ну суть от этого собственно не меняется:
public static final int COMPLETE = 0;
а что дальше, что писать в обработчике клика?

Answer (score 2):

В общем так (извини не будет ни строчки кода, просто наброски)

1. Надо создать собсно БД (через класс `SQLiteOpenHelper`)
2. Внутри БД надо создать таблицу (SQL выражение `CREATE TABLE` исполняемое через `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()`) с хотя бы одним полем - ну тем самым куда вы собираетесь пихать сохраняемое значение
3. Для сохранения данных надо писать в эту таблицу или через `SQLiteDatabase.insert()` - вставка новой записи или `SQLiteDatabase.update()` - обновление записи

В общем ради одного значения - это жестоко. SQLite имеет смысл когда структура данных более сложна нежели 1 поле.

Comment: А запись происходит по клику на определенный пункт, после чего обновляется список, и в зависимости от условия нажатый пункт принимает те свойства, которые мне нужно, так?

Comment: прочитай любую статью по работе с бд в андроиде и такие вопросы отпадут сами.. сейчас ты путаешь логику программы с местом хранения данных

Comment: Суть в том, что мне и хочется узнать как связать логику и место хранения.

Comment: Ну и не ради одного значения, у меня база, в которой хранятся пункты этого самого списка. Причем списков 2, по этому в там 2 таблицы. Это я к тому, что база не будет состоять из одного поля.